# How to get your https decryption key

Tags: ssl, encryption, https

I've read somewere how https encryption and decryption works.

But that made me curious if you could get someones https decryption key by running some kind of command

Comment: TLS is typically performed via _symmetric_ encryption, where the keys are exchanged via _asymmetric_ (normally RSA or ECC) encryption.

Comment: You can try commanding the gods to send you the key, other than that I don't understand where this command would be run or what it would be.

Comment: So @JamesKPolk Are you saying it isnt possible or you just dont know how to do it?

Comment: @jhpratt this is giving extra information about the topic, but do you know if its possible what I asked?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: "https" is just HTTP over SSL. SSL/TLS is designed to be secure. There have been various flaws found against various versions, configurations, ciphersuites, etc. I can't tell if your question about "running a command" alludes to one of these flaws, or to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running a command from your client: no. Really, where would the security be then. Believe it or not, all this has been well thought out and vetted by serious cryptographers.

But you can get the decryption key, [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) the server is vulnerable or you coerce a server admin, then you can get the certificate private key. Short of that no.